# Filter array to keep elements where the key exists in the value string

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring, filtering

I need to filter my flat, associative array of string-type values by checking if its key is found (case-sensitive) in its value as a substring.  In other words, if an element's key is in the element's value, I want to retain the element in the output array.

I can craft a classic `foreach()` loop with calls of `strpos()`, but this feels very pedestrian. Is there a more modern/elegant way do this?

My code:

```
$array = [
    'needle' => 'needle in haystack text',
    'Need' => 'another needle',
    'fine' => 'refined',
    'found' => 'Foundation',
    '' => 'non-empty haystack',
    'missing' => 'not here',
    'This is 0 in a haystack!',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $needle => $haystack) {
    if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
        $result[$needle] = $haystack;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'needle' => 'needle in haystack text',
  'fine' => 'refined',
  '' => 'non-empty haystack',
  0 => 'This is 0 in a haystack!',
)
```

Comment: That is demonstrated by `['fine' => 'refined']`.  It should be kept because the key exists in the value (anywhere, no word boundaries are needed).

Comment: Ok, so it is about the needle  just anywhere in the string.

Comment: We can also use a regex match like `array_filter($array, fn($v, $k) => preg_match('/'.preg_quote($k).'/', $v) === 1, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)` although `str_contains` is the neatest because of it's syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP5.6, [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) gained the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag.  This makes `array_filter()` an equivalent functional-style technique.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jQ7K4))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($haystack, $needle) {
            return strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    )
);
```

One advantage of this is that `$result` doesn't need to be declared.  On the other hand, despite the fact that it can technically be written as a one-liner, it would make a very long line of code -- something that puts the code near or over the soft character limit per line according to [PSR-12 coding standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#:%7E:text=2.3%20Lines,more%20than%2080%20characters%20each.).  So there is very little to compel you to change your code so far.

The good news is that PHP8 introduced [`str_contains()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) specifically to offer a clean, native, case-sensitive function to replace `strpos()` and its obligatory strict boolean `false` check.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F5c6C))

```
var_export(
    array_filter($array, 'str_contains', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
);
```

This returns the same desired output, is a functional-style, one-liner, and concisely spans just 59 characters.  I would recommend this approach.

To understand what is happening, the verbose syntax with `array_filter()` where `str_contains()` is not called by its string name looks like this:

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($haystack, $needle) => str_contains($haystack, $needle),
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    )
);
```